# ggplot2 - geom_text how to position the labels in the middle of the bars

Tags: r, ggplot2, label, bar-chart, geom-text

I need some help for a beginner with RStudio/ggplot2. I made a barplot with following code

```r
ggplot(match_player, aes(x = civ, fill = winner, group = winner), show.legend = T) +
  geom_bar() +
  geom_text(aes(label = stat(count)), stat = "count", color = "black", size = 3, position = "dodge")
```

barplot image

[image]

I would like to keep the labels in the middle of the belonging bar.

Comment: It would be easier to help if you create a small reproducible example. Read about [how to give a reproducible example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269).

Answer (score 1):

You're close, you just need to change the `position` argument in the text layer. Example with standard dataset below:

```r
library(ggplot2)

ggplot(mpg, aes(class, fill = as.factor(drv))) +
  geom_bar() +
  geom_text(stat = "count", position = position_stack(vjust = 0.5),
            aes(label = after_stat(count)))
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2021-02-02 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>

Comment: Thanks for the fast answer...worked perfectly for me :)